# Erro ao tentar gerar apk - Ionic v 3.20.1

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic3, npm, apk

Estou com o seguinte problema - estou tentando gerar uma APK em Ionic usando o comando abaixo:

```
 npm run generate-apk
```

Após rodar este comando, aparece a seguinte mensagem de erro ao final:

```
> cordova.cmd build android --release --buildConfig
Using "requireCordovaModule" to load non-cordova module "q" is not supported. Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.

        cordova.cmd build android --release --buildConfig exited with exit code 1.
```

Estou com as versões mais novas do node.js, angular, cordova, ionic e gradle instaladas na máquina (Windows 10).

Alguém sabe como resolver esse erro?

Comment: Tu tem as imagens baixadas das versões android no seu PC? Baixou o Android Studio e fez isso?

Comment: Eu estou com as versões do Android 6.0 até 10.0 todas instaladas no meu Android Studio. As variáveis do sistema foram configuradas.

Comment: Entendi, acrescenta essa info das imagens do android a sua pergunta, e dá uma olhada na resposta do Guilherme Nascimento.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

E porque não usa o próprio Ionic-cli para gerar o APK?

Ele te informa qualquer falta de dependência global, como se falta o `cordova` ou o `@ionic/app-scripts`, ele até lhe auxilia a instalar o que falta

O comando na pasta do projeto é este:

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Isto vai gerar o apk para debug, se quiser testar no emulador ou telefone o comando é:

```
ionic cordova run android -l -c
```

O `-l` é o parametro para fazer o livereload (você pode editar e ele atualiza diretamente sem precisar reinstalar o apk no emulador) e o `-c` é para exibir `console.log` e erros no terminal/cmd

---

Note que `ionic cordova build android` irá gerar o apk para testes/debug, se deseja publicar é necessário fazer uma série de passos:

### Gerar o APK para produção

Na pasta do projeto execute:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

No final do comando ele vai mostrar no console ou cmd aonde salvou o apk, copie o caminho

> Nota: este apk geralmente não é "instalável", pois precisará estar assinado

### Gerar uma assinatura

Primeiro, se for windows, a pasta `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.<versao do teu jdk 1.8>\bin\"` deve estar nas variáveis de ambiente (do sistema operacional), pois senão vai ter que digitar o caminho todo para acessar o programa `keytool` e `jarsigner`

Então navegue na pasta do projeto e execute isto:

```
keytool -genkey -v -keystore minhaassinatura.jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias nomedoprojetoouqualqueroutracoisa
```

Ele vai pedir para preencher alguns dados e depois vai pedir uma senha (chave), escolha uma chave, mas lembre-se de anota-la em algum lugar

### Assinando o APK

feito isto o seu jks está pronto, então o próximo passo é assinar o apk, no exemplo abaixo escrevi: `/CAMINHO/AONDE/ESTA/SALVO/O/APK/PRODUCAO.apk`, troque pelo caminho aonde o `ionic cordova build` gerou o apk

```
 jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore minhaassinatura.jks /CAMINHO/AONDE/ESTA/SALVO/O/APK/PRODUCAO.apk nomedoprojetoouqualqueroutracoisa
```

### Comprimindo

Após o processo de assinatura você deve comprimir o apk, tanto o programa `zipalign` quanto o programa `apksigner` ficam na pasta do android sdk, então esta pasta deve ser colocada nas variaveis de ambiente, do usuario ou do sistema operacional, exemplo se for windows e quiser adicionar via comando de linha/tempo de execução:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\<localização>\Android\Sdk\build-tools\<versão do sdk>
```

Ou adicione nas variáveis de ambiente mesmo. Feito isto, vamos comprimir:

```
zipalign -v 4 /CAMINHO/AONDE/ESTA/SALVO/O/APK/PRODUCAO.apk /novo/caminho/apk-comprimido.apk
```

O caminho `/novo/caminho/apk-comprimido.apk` é exemplo apenas, você deve escolher um caminho para salvar a versão comprimida do seu apk

### Verificando a assinatura

Para verificar a assintura execute:

```
apksigner verify /novo/caminho/apk-comprimido.apk
```

Se tiver feito tudo corretamente o seu apk deve estar pronto para publicar, o resto você deve fazer via:

- https://developer.android.com/distribute/console/

---

### App bundle vs APK

Se tem a intenção de usar *App bundle* ao invés de apk (ele gera apks para diferentes versões do android), então ao invés de gerar o apk com `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` basta executar:

```
ionic cordova prepare android
```

E então abrir a pasta `/projeto/platforms/android/` no androidstudio e fazer tudo por ele, eu não acredito que tenha muita vantagem para ionic ou outros projetos cordova usar isto, porque os recursos visuais geralmente são html, imagens e css, nada que realmente terá diferença entre as versões do android, ou seja é provavel que o ganho seja minimo.

Comment: Obrigada Guilherme, sua resposta foi bem completa! Agora estou tendo um erro diferente: Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect . Acredito que ainda falta alguma dependência...

Comment: @FlaviaPino por favor posta o log completo na pergunta, geralmente erros assim são consequências de erros anteriores.

Comment: eu descobri o que foi - era a versão do gradle! Percebi que o gradle tentava forçar um download da versão 4.10.3 e eu estava utilizando a mais recente (5.6.2). Baixei esta versão, e depois de configurar as variáveis rodei o seguinte comando - `.\gradlew`

Comment: @FlaviaPino eu também instalo manualmente o gradle e crio a variável de ambiente GRADLE_HOME e no PATH seto `;%GRADLE_HOME%\bin`, então reinicio (ou logoff) o sistema. Só tive dores de cabeça com o ADT mesmo sobre as versões do gradle, mas com o "compilador" via linha de comando não tive problemas.

Comment: Isso! Foi exatamente isso que fiz. Sua resposta foi realmente muito útil! Muito obrigada!

Answer (score 0):

Retornar uma versão anterior do Cordova pode resolver seu problema:

> npm install -g cordova@8.1.2

**Fonte:**

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55304065/cordova-error-using-requirecordovamodule-to-load-non-cordova-module-q-is-no

Comment: Então, eu já tinha visto posts relacionados e tentado instalar versões anteriores do cordova e do ionic antes de postar a pergunta, mas mesmo assim dá o mesmo erro...

Comment: E nesse outro caso que bate com o seu erro:Instead, add this module to your dependencies and use regular "require" to load it.


Substitua o requireCordovaModule por require :

requireCordovaModule("q") para require("q")